# CLIon - Undefined reference using SDL_TTF

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl, clion, sdl-ttf

I'm coding a small game and I'm using SDLs libraries for the graphics (with a CLion IDE). I've already downloaded SDL2, SDL2_image and SDL2_ttf. In the code, I include the three libraries and use TTF to make some text:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

bool foo() {

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (TTF_Init() == -1){
        cerr << "Error ." << endl;
    }

    TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("Sans.ttf", 20);
    SDL_Color color = {100, 0, 0};
    SDL_Surface* text;

    ...
```

Also, I've the following makefile linking this libraries:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")

set(CLIENT_FILES core/client.h core/client.cpp)
set(CONFIGURATION_FILES configuration/configurationClient.cpp configuration/configurationClient.h)
file(GLOB_RECURSE GAME_FILES "game/*.cpp" "game/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE MENU_FILES "menu/*.cpp" "menu/*.h")

add_executable(client main.cpp ${CLIENT_FILES} ${MENU_FILES} ${CONFIGURATION_FILES} ${GAME_FILES})

include(FindPkgConfig)

PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image>=2.0.0)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf>=2.0.0)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(client common SDLPrimitives ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARIES})
```

My problem is that the IDE recognize the SDL_ttf library (it doesn't mark in red as an error the TTF functions), but when I try to compile the code, I got many undefined references.

```
CMakeFiles/client.dir/menu/menuClientVisual.cpp.o: In function `foo()':
source/client/menu/foo.cpp:137: undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
source/client/menu/foo.cpp:141: undefined reference to `TTF_OpenFont'
source/client/menu/foo.cpp:145: undefined reference to `TTF_RenderText_Solid'
source/client/menu/foo.cpp:152: undefined reference to `TTF_RenderText_Solid'
source/client/menu/foo.cpp:157: undefined reference to `TTF_SetFontStyle'
source/client/menu/foo.cpp:160: undefined reference to `TTF_RenderText_Solid'
```

Any idea?

Comment: It isn't linking against the TTF library. Have a glance at the generated Makefile to see if its attempting to link the TTF library and whether its set to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

try including:

```
find_library(SDL2TTF_LIBRARIES SDL_ttf)
```

Comment: I'm stil getting the same error. I think that find_library and PKG_SEARCH_MODULO do almost the same, don't they?